# Limits class getDatabaseTime() and getLimitDatabaseTime() methods

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

I notice that the developer console autocomplete shows getDatabaseTime() and getLimitDatabaseTime() methods on the Limits class. Neither appears in the [**documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) and they don't show up at all in Google search results. Both return 0 in synchronous and asynchronous contexts.

What are these for? Part of a new governor limit that hasn't been fully implemented yet maybe?

Comment: I feel like I saw it somewhere... maybe it got removed.